# Google Chrome Extension: Omnibox Keyword How To?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome 'search extension' has a keyword and I want to take the user's input to trigger a search query. In my extension's manifest file I have declared:

```
"omnibox": { "keyword" : "i" },
```

When I type 'i' into the Omnibox and hit TAB/SPACE,  I see my extension take effect... however, when I then type a search query and press ENTER (or select the suggested command), nothing happens.

Here is the sample I am using, found at Google Code > Omnibox:

```
// This event is fired each time the user updates the text in the omnibox,
// as long as the extension's keyword mode is still active.

chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener(function(text) {
  var serviceCall2 = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=' + text;
});

// This event is fired with the user accepts the input in the omnibox.

chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener(function(text) {  
  chrome.windows.create({"url": serviceCall2});
});
```

Is there any other code that I'm missing or is my above code wrong?

Comment: Where is this code located in your extension?

Comment: It is in a file called background.js, which is declared as a "background: script" in the manifest file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your two events are identical. I assume it's a copy-paste error.

   The correct event to fire each time the text changes is `chrome.omnibox.onInputChanged`
2. Your code cannot work anyway, since `serviceCall2` is local to the first message listener. It is undefined in the second.
3. You don't need two listeners to begin with, this should work:

   ```
   chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener(function(text) { 
     var serviceCall2 = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=' + text;
     chrome.windows.create({"url": serviceCall2});
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you for assistance, the error in the first listener was that it is supposed to have been 'onInputChanged' but will I still be needing that if the onInputEntered listener does it all?

Comment: `onInputChanged` is used to provide suggestions. If you don't need that, you don't need the listener. It is possible that your code threw an error because of that (wrong signature for the callback, it's `function(text, suggest)`)

Comment: I have tested your snippet and it works perfectly. I won't be using the suggestions function. Thanks!